# How to use basic_istream when you have a std::string

Tags: c++

I have a function that uses basic_istream as an argument, and I have a std::string with the data I need to pass it. How do I do that?

Comment: It cannot possibility use "`basic_istream` as an argument", because that's a template. Why don't you show us actual code so we can solve the actual problem?

Comment: This looks like a homework question to me.

Comment: basic_istream is for input, you read from it. Do you mean you want to read it into a stream or you have a basic_ostream? Presumably your function is templated on the underlying character type.

Comment: I don't have actual code. It's not a homework question. I just don't grok the iostream world in STL and have avoided using it in general. I appreciate you looking at it nonetheless.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put the string data into a stream:

```
std::string x;
std::stringstream ss(x); // put string into stream

function_taking_stream(ss);
```

Comment: That's all it takes? Wow, I seriously overblew this problem. I did spend a quality hour or so trying to understand MSDN ... thank you very much! As soon as my development VM reboots I will give that a shot.

Comment: Yahoo! That was it. Thank you very much, GMan!

Answer (score 3):

A full working example showing how to parse a json string using boost property_tree:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
using boost::property_tree::ptree;

int main ()
{
  std::string jsonString ("{ \"my key\": \"my value\" }");
  ptree pt;
  std::stringstream ss(jsonString);
  read_json(ss, pt);
  std::cout << pt.get<std::string>("my key") << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I have a function that uses basic_istream as an argument...*

So I'm assuming you have a function that accepts a variable of a type specialized from the basic_istream template.

*...and I have a std::string with the data I need to pass it.*

So I'm assuming you want to feed this data into the istream argument.

*How do I do that?*

You don't.  You can't feed output to an input stream!

Comment: I should have been more precise. I am trying to use boost::property_tree::read_json. That takes two styles of signature, one using a filename, the other a basic_istream. I have a std::string containing which I want to parse. I can (a) create a temp file, (b) write my JSON string to it, (c) close the file, (d) call the read_json function (which works as expected) and (e) remove the temp file. I was hoping to use the other read_json signature which had basic_istream and somehow pass my JSON string into that, to avoid the whole temp file thing. Not critical, just cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP means he has a `basic_istream<E>` to read from and wants to read to a `std::string`, not to a `std::basic_string<E>`.

You should probably write to the basic_string first then convert that to a std::string. If you want to ensure the conversion is correct you probably want a proper UTF-8 to UTF-16 converter.

If you know you are dealing with only ASCII bytes you can do something like:

```
std::basic_string<E> strTemp;
is >> strTemp;
std::string str( strTemp.begin(), strTemp.end() );
```

If you have a `basic_ostream<E>` you can similarly first construct a `basic_string<E>` from your std::string and then write that to the stream.

You can "specialise" your template function so that if E happens to be char the conversion is quick. For that purpose you can input the two strings as non-const references and the specialised version could just "swap".